# What's the best practice to parallelize steps in a transient AWS EMR launched from a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Suppose that a lambda function is invoked when receiving a file in a S3 bucket.
This lambda function is in charge of processing this file with some spark jobs submitted in a transient AWS EMR. The spark jobs are the following :

- step A : run preprocessing pipeline

  - input : `s3://data-bucket/raw/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
  - output : `s3://data-bucket/preprocessed/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
- step B1 : run feature extraction pipeline 1

  - input : `s3://data-bucket/preprocessed/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
  - output : `s3://data-bucket/features/pipeline1/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
- step C1 : run machine learning pipeline 1

  - input : `s3://data-bucket/features/pipeline1/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
  - output : `s3://data-bucket/predictions/pipeline1/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
- step B2 : run feature extraction pipeline 2

  - input : `s3://data-bucket/preprocessed/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
  - output : `s3://data-bucket/features/pipeline2/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
- step C2 : run machine learning pipeline 2

  - input : `s3://data-bucket/features/pipeline2/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`
  - output : `s3://data-bucket/predictions/pipeline2/file.YYYY-MM-DD.HH-MM-SS.csv`

I can run these steps sequentially  (A, B1, C1, B2, C2) with the following code :

```py
import boto3

emr = boto3.client('emr')

# code to define spark_submits = {"A": ..., "B1": ..., ....}

steps = [
    {
        'Name': step_name,
        'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER' if step_name == 'A' else 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 's3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
            'Args': [*spark_submit_cmd[step_name]]
        }
    },
    for step_name, spark_submit_cmd in spark_submits.items()
]

response = emr.run_job_flow(
    Name='MyJobFlow',
    Steps=steps,
    # other configurations and parameters ...
)
```

However, it is really time consuming and I would prefer to parallelize (B1, C1) and (B2, C2).
Note that A must be finished before running B1/B2 and B1/B2 must be finished before running C1/C2.

How to achieve this with the best practices ? I would like to avoid coding a dirty bash script to achieve that... Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sequential requirements, AWS Step Functions might be a good candidate for orchestrations. Especially since you'd be able to keep all of the ordering logic outside of your Lambda.

[AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/step-functions/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpJf249PxgwMVk0t_AB098QOOEAAYASAAEgIPjfD_BwE&trk=84951f72-fb87-4173-b32b-ced557711d5a&sc_channel=ps&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIpJf249PxgwMVk0t_AB098QOOEAAYASAAEgIPjfD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!658520967056!!!g!!!19852662602!149878733660)

Comment: The EMR is currently instanciated given some environment variables (configured in the lambda) which depend on the environment (development and stagging environments are "isolated" using different bucket and stuff like that). I guess I must use CloudFormation to templatize the step functions. But I have no idea how to do it.